# Is Horizonstal/Vertical Bias value in Android's ConstraintLayout always respected?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I was wondering if the applied horizontal/vertical bias value is "absolute" and if I, for example, set the horizontal bias to `0` then the constrained View will stay on the left side of the constraint no matter what.

Would stretching its parent make it have an offset of `+2dp` or more at some point?

I essentially want to have two views stick together without using LinearLayout.

[image: moving image]

[image: layout position]